# What is storage factor in total RAID capacity formula given by Wolframalpha?

Tags: raid

What is meant by "storage factor" (F) in this total RAID capacity calculation formula?

> T = nFD

Where T - total RAID capacity, n - number of drives, D - drive size and F - storage factor

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=raid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID uses some portion of the disks to provide redundancy, in order to handle the failure of some of the disks in the RAID array.

The exception to the above is RAID 0, which is striping with no parity or redundancy. If any disk in a RAID 0 array fails, with very few exceptions, the entire array fails. (The times when you are able to recover data from a RAID 0 array with failed disks, it's not thanks to RAID.)

**This can be expressed mathematically such that the total usable storage capacity of a RAID array is equal to the number of disks multiplied by the size of those disks multiplied by some factor that is less than or equal to one.** Hence T=nDF, or written differently, T=nFD.

RAID provides different [levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels), which allow for different trade-offs in terms of usable storage capacity as well as performance and data integrity characteristics. (Unlike what might be implied by the term "level", higher-numbered levels are not necessarily better. It depends very much on what you are trying to achieve.) The commonly used RAID levels are:

- RAID 0: Striping with no redundancy at all. All raw disk space of the devices that make up the array is usable for storage, thus the efficiency factor = 1. Can be used with any number of disks but can not survive the failure of any disks in the array.
- RAID 1: Mirroring but no striping. Out of each group, one disk's worth of storage is available, thus the efficiency factor = 1/n for some number of disks n. Often used with two-way mirrors (two disks in each group, efficiency factor = 1/2 = 0.5), sometimes with three-way mirrors (efficiency factor = 1/3 ~ 0.33), but rarely more than that because at that point the gains do not outweigh the cost. Can be used with any number of disks (in some cases even with a single disk) and can survive the failure of all but one disk in every group.
- RAID 5: Striping with single parity but no mirroring. Out of each group, one disk's worth of storage is used to store parity information, thus the efficiency factor is (n-1)/n for some number of disks n. Can be used with no less than two disks, but three is the minimum where it makes sense (otherwise just use a mirror) and can survive the failure of any one disk in every group.
- RAID 6: Striping with double parity but no mirroring. Out of each group, two disks' worth of storage are used to store parity information, thus the efficiency factor is (n-2)/n for some number of disks n. Can be used with no less than three disks, but four is the minimum where it makes sense (otherwise again just use a mirror) and can survive the failure of any two disks in every group.

Some [vendor-specific or non-standard RAID levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Non-standard_levels) are also available and in relatively common use. These generally provide some specific benefits that warrant the resultant vendor lock-in, such as allowing odd array layouts or solving the [RAID 5 write hole problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Atomicity:_including_parity_inconsistency_due_to_system_crashes).

For extremely small (in terms of disk space) arrays, one needs to account for that the RAID itself requires a small amount of metadata to keep track of the layout of the array. This can be safely ignored for everyday purposes, and different RAID controllers or systems differ in where exactly they store this data (generally the choice being between on the disks of the array or in some kind of non-volatile memory on the controller).

In the general case, RAID levels can also be nested. For example, you can have an array using RAID 0 where each group referenced by the RAID 0 array consists of some non-zero number of RAID 1 groups. In this case, the efficiency is calculated first for the subgroups, then the larger groups, then for the whole array.

As you can see, **it is not possible to give any one number for the RAID storage factor** as it depends very much on the specific RAID configuration in use.

Answer (score 0):

Its a constant, depending on what sort of RAID level you use - in this case it should correlate to "storage efficiency".

[image]

Comment: Except it shouldn't be a constant. It isn't even a constant in the case of a single RAID 1 group (for RAID 1, it would be 1/n where n is the number of drives in the group). And a RAID 0 (striped configuration) of two two-disk RAID 1 groups (mirrors) cannot possibly survive three failures; it is guaranteed to *fail* by the time the third disk fails because there is no way three failures can leave two two-way mirrors functional, and might fail by the time the second disk fails (happens if the two failed disks belong to the same RAID 1 group, with two-way mirrors).

Comment: We're talking 'usable space' though =, in terms of what F is, and I er.. picked a random screenshot while messing with it. And yeah, terrible example, and I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define F in terms of T instead of the other way round. `F = T / ND`. Note that this assumes all N drives/volumes have equal size. E.g. 5x2TB = 10TB, but with RAID5 you only have 8GB, so that's F = 0.8 = 8/10. Note also T is the *net* storage after implementing RAID.

A better formula would be `efficiency = Net storage / Total storage`, because this does not care about variable disk size. Another option is to take D as the smallest of the drives. E.g. 2x2TB + 2x1TB in RAID1 would give 2TB net, using 4x1TB of space for the array, giving a F of 0.5--excluding the 2x1TB spare space left on the 2TB drives.